# Postgres: granting access to a role/user for future tables created by a different role/user

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, migration, flyway

I'm building a spring boot application. Flyway database migrations are executed at the application startup.

I decided to use two different roles: **role__app** (**read/write** rights on tables, sequences in **app** schema) and **role__migration** (**advanced** rights in **app**/**migration** schemas).

Flyway migrations are executed under **role__migration** so it becomes the owner of the created objects. I thought that the following statements would help:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA app GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO role__app;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA app GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO role__app;
```

But when the new tables are added to the **app** schema the **user__app** (belongs to the **role__app**) doesn't have access to the tables.

Is it possible to maintain such a flow (with app, migrattion users/roles) by Postgres or by any other means?

---

As a side note I should mention that I run the following statements on the target database:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
REVOKE ALL ON DATABASE myDb FROM PUBLIC;
```

---

Update 1

I added the `FOR ROLE` clause, yet I'm still getting the permission denied message for a created table (**app.property**) in app schema for user **user__app**. The owner of the table is **user__mig**.

Update 2

After logging in as postgres user in dbeaver we can see that **user__mig** has all necessary permissions ticked whereas the **user__app** has no permissions on the **app.property** table at all:

[image]

---

Here is a gist to reproduce the problem: https://gist.github.com/happygrizzly/849a6a791f028ba5b191f73180ae35d1

Comment: Did you grant usage on the schema app to role_app?

Comment: @Jeremy yes, I did

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER role__migration ...
```

If you omit the `FOR USER` clause, the privileges are only granted on objects created by the user who ran `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.

With the above statement, the privileges are granted when `role__migration` creates an object. That does *not* extend to members of the role `role__migration`.

Comment: Is it essential to write `FOR USER`, can it be substituted by `FOR ROLE`?

Comment: Initially I followed the example shown in [the article at amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/blogs/database/managing-postgresql-users-and-roles/). I've read your edit and now understand the thing about the direct **role** and its perm. delegation. I see the point of using multiple users as they represent different  logins. Regarding the migration flow, I probably can use single migration login (`role__migration` + `WITH LOGIN`).

Comment: in this example is `role__migration` a user or a role?

Comment: @SabrinaLeggett That is the same thing in PostgreSQL :^)